# Can't read a raw cgi response with python

Tags: python, cgi, response

I'm trying to read a raw CGI response from an old website to simply parse the data and can't seem to read it with requests or urllib.

Python throws the following exception:
Exception has occurred: requests.exceptions.ConnectionError
('Connection aborted.', BadStatusLine('60.000\n',))

The data loads from 'http://powermeter.tradesmanmfg.ca:9900/basic.cgi?sid=0.487933' and works only in IE, but I'd like to parse this raw data directly in python.  I've tried this but can't get any response without the 'BadStatusLine' response.  My code is below: How can I read this into python to parse?

```
import requests
webpage = 'http://powermeter.tradesmanmfg.ca:9900/basic.cgi?sid=0.487933'
r = requests.get(webpage, stream=True)
print(r.raw.data)
```

Comment: It seems to return HTTP 0.9 formatted data which `requests` doesn't like https://bugs.python.org/issue26578

Comment: OK thanks yes.  urllib doesn't seem to work with it either.  Any idea what python module might read these then?  Just need a way to parse the data that URL gives.?